# Displaying a certain page in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm developing an online area for my clients. Rather than go down the road of fixing bugs for IE, I'd like to display a page if they're using IE to say 'This doesn't work with IE, please use Firefox, Chrome or Safari'.

Any ideas on how I might do this are gratefully received!

Thanks in advance,

Tom Perkins

Comment: Not really an answer so adding this as a comment. Basically I don't know of a way to reliably determine the browser - from what I have heard people can change what is sent to the server in the page header, so getting the browser name on server side is unreliable. JavaScript, as mentioned in a couple of other answers, may be an option - however the user can simply switch this off (about 5%, the last time I looked, have it switched off) and my guess is that JS would just pick up what the server is told (i.e. if they change what is sent to the server then JS will pick up the new value).

Comment: Someone correct me if I am wrong in my last comment - but thats how I think it is.

Answer (score 1):

Use Conditional Comments.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You might just use a bit of Javascript to detect the browser... 

You could replace the "alert("Hi, Explorer User!");" line below with javascript redirection to another page.

```
var browserName=navigator.appName; 
if (browserName=="Netscape")
{ 
 alert("Hi Netscape User!");
}
else 
{ 
 if (browserName=="Microsoft Internet Explorer")
 {
  alert("Hi, Explorer User!");
 }
 else
  {
    alert("What ARE you browsing with here?");
   }
}
```

Comment: This can also be done on the server side via looking at the HTTP Headers. Browser detection is also helpful for css. You can attach a class of ie, ie7, firefox, etc to a containing element (such as the body) to define css rules that target a specific browser rather than having a separate style sheet. This is a bit cleaner as most of your css should cover all browsers and only a small fraction will be needed for exceptions. Also much cleaner than using "hacks" that may break for future browser versions.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for the [CSS Conditional Comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

```
<!--[if IE]>
Special instructions for IE here
<![endif]-->
```